# With nginx proxy/rewrite can I keep the original URL in the browser's Location field?

Tags: nginx

Using `nginx.conf` features like `proxy-pass`/`rewrite`, can I keep the *original* URL in the browser's Location field?

I have several PlayFramework apps running on different ports (9001, 9002, ...) with proxy forwarding set up via `nginx.conf`.  People browse to them as:

- `http://domain.name/App1/`
- `http://domain.name/App2/`
- *etc*.

My `nginx.conf` entries look like this:

```
location /App1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
    rewrite ^/App1/(.*) http://domain.name:9001/$1;
}
```

If I ask for `http://domain.name/App1/`, what I see in the browser's Location field is `http://domain.name:9001`.  What I wish I saw was `http://domain.name/App1/`, that is, I want the **name** App1 to remain in the URI, and I'd rather not expose the port number.

Let's say App1 has a link `/location/ABC`.  When I click on it I see `http://domain.name:9001/location/ABC` when I wish I saw `http://domain.name/App1/location/ABC`.

Can I achieve this with `nginx.conf`?

P.S.  I put `http://domain.name` explicitly in the rewrite rule because without it I was getting `localhost` in the browser, and my browser's localhost is not the same as the server's.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrites issue redirects for browser.

If you just want to mount several locations from upstreams - you do not need rewrites, just use:

```
location /App1/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001/;
}
```

But apps should use relative links or account for their absolute location.

For more complex url manipulation you can use `break`-rewrites:

```
location /App1/ {
    rewrite ^/App1/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's actually the first thing I tried.  However, when I browse to http://domain.name/App1/, I get an error Action Not Found (For request 'GET /App1/'), because the Play app is not expecting to see its own name in the URL.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your second full example above with and without the trailing slash.  I got to the app's home page OK, but when I clicked on a link which is /location/ABC, I got http://domain.name/location/ABC -> 404 Not Found.  By relative do you mean the link should have been location/ABC?  I don't know if omitting the leading slash would work with PlayFramework routing.

Comment: Yes, but this can be hard to track, easier is to make app to add prefix to all absolute urls