# How to link Google Could Stoage into ASP.NET Core 2.2 project as file provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, google-cloud-storage, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a project that is written using `C#` on the top of ASP.NET Core 2.2 framework using the MVC architecture.

This project contains lots of images (150GB worth) which is causing my VPS to run out of space.

I decided to subscribe in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/) to allow me to host the images on a different service than my VPS. This will allow me to free up my VPS while hosting the images elsewhere. Also, this will cost me under $10 a month at most which is much cheaper than upgrading my VPS.

However, I am not sure how I can integrate my [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/) account with my application so that the images still show the same URL while being hosting on [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/)

Currently, I am using `PhysicalFileProvider` to point any link that starts with mydomain.com/photos to a different physical path on my VPS (i.e `c:/photos`) like so

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("c:\\photos"),
    RequestPath = "/photos"
});
```

How can add [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing-summary/) as a file provider in my Asp.net Core 2.2 project?

Comment: does your images need authentication ?

Comment: No. there are open for public but need to show up ar mydomain.com/photos/...

Comment: why not custom domain photos.mydomain.com ?

Comment: Because the images are shared by multiple domain acting like a virtual link to the images folder

Comment: ok , let me check

Comment: what about nginx/iis rewrite ? [With nginx proxy/rewrite can I keep the original URL in the browser's Location field? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774906/with-nginx-proxy-rewrite-can-i-keep-the-original-url-in-the-browsers-location-f)

Comment: Please look at my updated question. I think this could be done using FileProvider with Core 2.2

Comment: ok , maybe this then [Google Cloud Storage mount on windows - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/831179/google-cloud-storage-mount-on-windows)

Comment: is your VPS  hosted in Google Cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything exists (either provided by Microsoft or by a third party) right now.

You could try at creating an implementation of `IFileProvider` using the [Google Cloud Storage SDK](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-csharp) available on NuGet with the [`Google.Cloud.Storage.V1`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1) package.

Also, I suggest that you have a look at a custom implementation of `IFileProvider` that uses Azure blob storage for inspiration. You can read a blog post [here](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/08/azure-blob-storage-ifileprovider-for-asp-net-core/) and have a look at the code on GitHub in the [`filipw/Strathweb.AspNetCore.AzureBlobFileProvider`](https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.AspNetCore.AzureBlobFileProvider) repository.